# scipy.rfft yields halved frequency

Tags: python, scipy, fft

I'm trying to detect certain frequencies in the audio output of the computer. For some reason, the frequencies that I find are roughly half the expected value. The total program is a little long, so I'll only post the relevant parts.

I use a fork of pyaudio to stream the output sound (https://github.com/intxcc/pyaudio_portaudio). From this, I read in some audiodata, apply scipy.rfft and plot the spectrum.

```
frames = np.frombuffer(
            self.stream.read(int(self.sampleRate/10)), np.int16)
xf, yf = audioUtils.getSpectrum(frames, self.sampleRate)
self.plotWidget.plot(xf, yf)
```

The rfft:

```
def getSpectrum(frames, sampleRate):
    n = len(frames) 

    yf = rfft(frames)
    yf = np.abs(yf)
    xf = rfftfreq(n, 1 / sampleRate)
```

I've been testing the code with an online tone generator (https://www.szynalski.com/tone-generator/), which produces the following results for a 10 kHz tone:

[image: Spectrum after analysing a 10 kHz tone]

For some reason, the main peak is at half the expected frequency. Furthermore, there seems to be a peak mirrored around ~12 kHz. Here is a second example of 20 kHz

[image: Spectrum after analysing a 20 kHz tone]

My sampling rate is 44100 Hz.
Am I not doing the rfft right?

Comment: The calculation in `getSpectrum` looks OK.  I suspect the problem is with your sample or its purported sample rate.  Test your code with a simple example instead of something streamed from `pyaudio`, e.g. this creates  2 seconds of a pure 1000 Hz tone: `fs = 44100; t = np.arange(2*fs)/fs; signal = np.sin(2*np.pi*1000*t)`

Comment: Is your audio signal in stereo maybe?

Comment: Alright, your example produces the correct output. That rules out anything on the fft & plotting part. I've found that if I increase the frames_per_buffer parameter of the audiostream, the measured frequency will be exactly half of the expected one. I can just double the frequencies after and it'll work for now. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, that was the problem. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the stream was reading in audio from a 2-channel source. A simple splice fixed it.

The working code:

```
frames = np.frombuffer(
            self.stream.read(int(self.sampleRate)), np.int16)
frames = frames[::2]
xf, yf = audioUtils.getSpectrum(frames, self.sampleRate)
self.plotWidget.plot(xf, yf)
```